# GWT - Get button's "addClickHandler" from a Widget

Tags: java, gwt, button, widget, handler

first of all Im working on a time tracking page with login authentication using ldap.
For the login I created a dialogbox setting verticalpanel as its widget. My verticalpanel contains two textboxes to enter username/password and one button to send data to the ldap server.

On module load the dialogbox pops up and gets the time tracking content on login success.

To my question:
"LoginWidget" and "LoginClickHandler" have separated classes, hence I need to get the login button on module load to add "LoginClickHandler".

What is the best way to handle this? - since I know that my solution isnt that good.

**LoginWidget class**

```
public class LoginWidget{
     private Button loginButton;
     private DialogBox dialogBox;
     private TextBox tbxUser;
     private PasswordTextBox tbxPw;
     private Label lblUser;
     private Label lblPW;
     private Label lblError;

public LoginWidget(){
    dialogBox = new DialogBox();
    tbxUser = new TextBox();
    tbxPw = new PasswordTextBox();
    lblUser = new Label();
    lblPW = new Label();
    lblError = new Label();
    dialogBox.setText("Login");
    dialogBox.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    loginButton = new Button("Login");
    // set the id of a widget by accessing its Element
    loginButton.getElement().setId("closeButton");
    final HTML serverResponseLabel = new HTML();
    VerticalPanel dialogVPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    dialogVPanel.addStyleName("dialogVPanel");
    dialogVPanel.add(lblUser);
    lblUser.setText("User:");
    dialogVPanel.add(tbxUser);
    dialogVPanel.add(lblPW);
    lblPW.setText("PW:");
    dialogVPanel.add(tbxPw);
    dialogVPanel.add(lblError);
    dialogVPanel.add(serverResponseLabel);
    dialogVPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    dialogVPanel.add(loginButton);
    dialogBox.setWidget(dialogVPanel);
    dialogBox.show();
    dialogBox.center();
}

public Button getLoginButton(){
    return loginButton;     
}

    public DialogBox getDialogBox(){
    return dialogBox;
}

public TextBox getTbxUser(){
    return tbxUser;
}

public TextBox getTbxPw(){
    return tbxPw;
}

public Label getLblError(){
    return lblError;
}
}
```

**LoginClickHandler class**

```
public class LoginClickHandler implements ClickHandler {
/**
*/
private LoginWidget lw;
private ServiceImplURL serviceImplURL;
private TimeTracking dtt = new TimeTracking();

public LoginClickHandler(ServiceImplURL sIU, LoginWidget _lw){
    /**
    */
    this.lw = _lw;
    this.serviceImplURL = sIU;
}

public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    /**
    */
    serviceImplURL.getRpcLdap().authenticate(lw.getTbxPw().getText(), lw.getTbxUser().getText(), new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
        /**
        */
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Boolean isLdapAuthOk) {   
            /**
            */
            if(isLdapAuthOk){                       
                lw.getDialogBox().hide();
                User user = new User(lw.getTbxUser().getText(), lw.getTbxPw().getText());
                serviceImplURL.getRpcSession().setUsername(user.getUsername(), new AsyncCallback<Void>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                serviceImplURL.getRpcDB().insertUser(user.getUsername(), new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
                    /**
                    */
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        /*
                         * connection error to implement
                         */                                     
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                        /*
                         * do nothing
                         */                                     
                    }
                });
                dtt.loadContent();
            }
            else{
                lw.getLblError().setStyleName("error");
                lw.getLblError().setText("Passwort oder Username falsch!");
            }                           
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
}
```

**My Entrypoint**

```
@Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {    
        /**
        */
        loadLoginWidget();

    }

    /**
     * Creates the login pop up.
     */
    public void loadLoginWidget(){
        /**
        */
        LoginWidget lw = new LoginWidget();
        LoginClickHandler lch = new LoginClickHandler(serviceImplURL, lw);
        lw.getLoginButton().addClickHandler(lch);
    }
```

I already tried to extend Button but I dont think its a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a listener class (eg. your `LoginClickHandler`) to the view constructor:

```
public LoginWidget( LoginClickHandler listener ) 
{
    ...
    loginButton.addClickHandler( listener )
    ...
}
```

More generally you may want to interject an interface defining the actions and have `LoginClickHandler` implement it:

```
public interface LoginListener
{
    void onLogin();
    ...
}

public class LoginWidget
{
    public LoginWidget( LoginListener listener ) 
    {
        this.listener = listener;
        Button loginButton = new Button( "Login" );
        loginButton.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler()
        { 
            public void onClick( ClickEvent event ) { listener.onLogin(); }
        } );
    }
    ...
}
```

and finally

```
public class LoginClickHandler implements LoginListener
{
    @Override public void onLogin()
    {
        serviceImplURL.getRpcLdap()...
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public void loadLoginWidget()
{
    LoginWidget lw = new LoginWidget( new LoginClickHandler() );
    ...
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: You're welcome. I outlined a slightly more complex setup that gives a better separation between view and control, which may be handy when your project grows. Good luck and happy coding :-)

Comment: does the interface have to extend ClickHandler because the onLogin method's already existing?